# Evaluation of Cassandra ring

Tags: cassandra, evaluation

I am not sure if this is the right place to post this but let me know if not. So, I have a Cassandra ring with 16 nodes which contains ~1.1 billion records. I would like to know how can I evaluate this cluster. What kind of metrics are important to collect and how (i.e. memory consumption during the inserts?)? For example writing/reading speed? Compression ratio? Compacted partitions? Should I also use Jconsole somehow?

Feel free to post any documentation or links.

Comment: Voting to have this moved to dba.stackexchange.com, as that's more for DBA ops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important metrics to watch for on an Apache Cassandra cluster:

- Java heap usage
- reads/sec
- writes/sec
- current compactions
- disk space
- disk latency
- disk IOPS
- nodes down
- CPU (although, I wouldn't alert on it)

That should be a good enough list to help you get started.  Check out the [Monitoring](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/metrics.html) page from the official docs for more information and additional metrics.

Comment: I do have so many question on these! So, the java Heap Space on every node is -Xmx: 4G. There are so many metrics in the jconsole and I am not sure what to look! Concerning i.e. the reads/sec and writes/sec should I check org.apache.acassandra.metrics.ClientRequest.Read.Latency.Attributes.Count or nodetool tablestats <keyspace>.<table>? They give slightly different number. Also, should I sum from every node in order to take the total reads/sec? For compaction, do you mean the mean size of a compacted partition or the maximum compacted partition? My compaction strategy is the default one.